70s Short Story Dream Time Travel Experiment: Man going back in time and slaughtered by the Huns?
I am looking for a short story I read in a collection of Science Fiction short stories in the 1970s. A man is shut in a room by historians/scientists for several nights in a row, to what avail I do not remember. The experiment is successful, he tells them of a dream he experiences in the closed room of going back in time to the Huns (?). He is horrified by horses and hordes of Huns approaching - every night they close in on him a bit further. At the end it turns out that he is really living through the dreams - the door to the room is dented from sword hits and spear points from the inside and the people standing outside the room have to listen to battle noises, horses' hooves thundering, people wailing and clamouring from within. When at last they open the door, the man is dead, brutally slaughtered, cut to pieces. Please help!

This has a Poul Anderson flavor. He wrote stories that mixed historical references to ancient and mythical civilizations with time-traveling modern people. However, I don't recognize the plot.

Thanks a lot for your helpful comment - it wasn't Poul Anderson, but when doing research into him just now after your comment, I was able to retrace another of my evasive memories (Poul Anderson, The Long Remembering). So - thank you, too, for your help!

Poul Anderson is my favorite sci-fi/fantasy writer. I know his work pretty well. Glad I could help.

Duplicate of: Classic short story about a recurring dream of approaching death.

This sounds a bit like The Janissaries of Emilion by Basil Copper, which I've previously identified in Classic short story about a recurring dream of approaching death. However it was Ottoman warriors not Huns who eventually slaughtered the dreamer.
The story ends as you describe with screams being heard from the man's room:

The sanatorium was roused by the most appalling screams around four in the morning. The uproar had come from Farlow's room, and it was like nothing else in the Superintendent's experience. The first male nurse to look through the peephole in Farlow's door had a violent fit of vomiting and the matron fainted.

Then when the door is opened:

What Sondquist had told me and what the photographs depicted had been like something from an obscene slaughterhouse. For in Farlow's room, which was padded and contained no sharp edges of any kind, much less a weapon, the gutted, disembowelled, and eviscerated monstrosity which had once been my friend was spread about in carmine horror; there an eyeball, here a leg or an arm like some demoniac scene in a canvas by Bosch. Save that this was gory reality. No wonder the staff had fainted or that the ambulance attendants had used masks and tongs when clearing up.
Said Sondquist in a trembling voice as I took my leave, "Make no mistake about it, though the thing is scientifically impossible, Farlow had been hacked to pieces as surely as if a dozen men had attacked him with sharpened swords or knives!''


Yes! That's IT! Thank you. And now I can remember the title: Something with "Die Janitscharen" (The Janissaries), because I read it in German at the time. THANK YOU ever so much - the evasiveness of the title has been haunting me. You've put my mind to rest on this enigma.
